# On Hover add/remove class to div child

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to add a class to the child of a div that is actively being hovered? I tried to use this script:

```
            $('.star, .ship').hover(
            function()
            { 
                $(this).children().removeClass('hidden');               },
            function() 
            { 
                $('.child').addClass('hidden'); 
            }
            );
```

however it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `$('.child')` on line 7 to what you did on line 4: `$(this).children()`.

`$('.child')` would get anything with the class `child`, not the children of the object being un-hovered.

**Edit**: Your final code would look like:

```
$('.star, .ship').hover(function(){
    $(this).children().removeClass('hidden');
},function(){
    $(this).children().addClass('hidden'); 
});
```

Comment: I did this and now its working less. (EG before i could get it to add the class and the class would stay there, but now the class isn't even showing up)

Answer (score 1):

look into `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event handlers

Something like

```
$('.star, .ship').mouseenter(function{
    $(this).children().removeClass('hidden'); 
}) 

$('.star, .ship').mouseleave(function{
    $(this).children().addClass('hidden'); 
})
```